# Who is invoking kernel driver for Ethernet in Linux?

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, ethernet

I have already kernel driver and I want to implement some more functionality for it. 
And firstly, I was wandering if there is "somebody" who control this Ethernet driver in kernel space, or it's like if some app in user space need Ethernet communication, this Ethernet kernel driver will be called?
Is the system call that one who implements that interaction between kernel and user space application?